# Continue script back to beginning of while loop

Tags: powershell, infinite-loop

I'm trying to write a small utility that will test connectivity to some servers, and when there is a few seconds of packet loss to do something else.

However once that is done, I would like it to continue testing the connectivity, and so on without the script exiting. Primarily I am doing this as a learning exercise to create similar styles of scripts in the future for some daily tasks we do.

So far I've come up with a few variations of this, however I can't seem to get it to. So far I've come up with creating a function.

```
function ServerUp {
    while (Test-Connection -Cn $Server -BufferSize 16 -Count 4 -ea 0) {
        "Server is up"
    }
}
}

function ServerDown {
    while (!(Test-Connection -Cn $Server -BufferSize 16 -Count 4 -ea 0)) {
        "Connection to server went down"
    }
    {
    }
}

$Server = Read-Host -Prompt 'Input your server  name'

ServerUp 
ServerDown
```

I've played with a lot of different variations of this (for example creating an if statement after the `while` loop to do something when the `while` loop no longer is true etc.), but each time it seems to exit the script.

After doing some research, it seems like continue may be the way to make this happen but I can't seem to get that to work properly either.

Is this even possible without some kind of "goto" (which is not in PowerShell as far as I understand).

Comment: `for() { ServerUp; ServerDown }`

Comment: Thanks for the info, this also worked but I ended up using the info from the post below for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not combine the two checks into a single function and then put that inside a loop?

```
function Test-ServerConnection {
    if(Test-Connection -Cn $Server -BufferSize 16 -Count 4 -ea 0){
        "Server is up"
    } else {
        "Server is down"
    }
}

while($true){
    Test-ServerConnection
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but this was the most helpful answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Is this even possible without some kind of "goto" (Which is not in powershell as far as I understand).

It's not in PowerShell, and it's a shame. For exactly this reason - there is no loop which clearly says "loop forever". There are only ways to jam wrenches into the existing loops to bodge them and hold them open so they never exit.

```
while ($true) { 
    #code here
}


do {
    # code here
} while ($true)


do {
    # code here
} until ($false)


for () {
    # code here
}
```

`continue` is not useful here - it's for skipping the remainder of a loop block, and moving on to the next item.

Comment: Is there any language that has an explicit construct for infinite loops? AFAIK `while (true)` is what's commonly used to express this in most languages.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop#Language_support) Ada, Fortran, Go and Ruby have - but only Ada and Ruby have clear intent to me. [Rosettacode](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Loops/Infinite) says 4DOS Batch, AppleScript, AutoHotkey, Standard BASIC, Brat, CoffeeScript, Common Lisp, Haskell, Maple, Modula-2, Perl 6, PostScript, R, Rust, VB.Net  - all have infinite loop syntaxes that don't include a True condition. Some have the `loop {}` syntax I imagined PS could have. (and any language with `label start / goto start`)